# Is there a better way of handling a dynamic number of query parameters in an angular route and display them?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

i have a route with a dynamic number of parameters and i will display them in a componen with an async obersavable. *Everything work fine so far*.

Angula Version: 10

My questions are:

- Is there a simpler/shorter syntax for iterating through the
  queryParamsMap$ obersavable?
- Is my solution for routes with a dynamic
  number of parameters correct or will i run into problems?

**Route**

```
  {
    path: 'feature1',
    children: [{
      path: "**",      
      component:Feature1LayoutComponent
    }]
  },
```

**Component**

```
export class Feature1LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  queryParamsMap$: Observable<ParamMap>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.queryParamsMap$ = this.route.queryParamMap;    
  }

}
```

***Template***

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let key of (queryParamsMap$ | async ).keys">{{key}} : {{(queryParamsMap$ | async ).get(key)}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: One thing I'd say is each `async` pipe would trigger individual subscriptions. You could enclose the tag using `ng-container` to reuse the emissions: `<ng-container *ngIf="(queryParamsMap$ | async) as params"> <li *ngFor="let key of params.keys">{{ key }} : {{ params.get(key) }}</li> </ng-container>`.

Comment: thx Michael i like the ng-container solution